# UITableView cell having different identifiers for three different cell design

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reviews";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"recipes";
       static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"easy_tips";
    // Configure Cell

    NSString *type = [[myaray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    NSLog(@"types====%@",type);

    UITableViewCell *mycell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (type == CellIdentifier) {

    firstCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"First type %@", type);

    return cell;
    }else if (type == CellIdentifier1){


    SecondTableViewCell *cell1 =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];


        return cell1;

    }else if (type == CellIdentifier2){

    ThirdTableViewCell *cell2 =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell2;
    }

    return mycell;
}
```

I am getting only one cell every time it is first cell .

It is not going to if condition statement.
Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: For comparing two strings use isEqualToString: method.

Comment: Why you have the UITableViewCell, mycell outside the conditions? A good practise would be to have all kind of cells inside one of the conditions and the pattern should be "if", "else if" and at the end "else". That way if nothing matches, your method would return the cell inside the else statement. Try putting a break point inside each loop to see if for different types, your code is entering the appropriate condition block.

Comment: What is the cell identifier for your cell inside your storyboard?

Comment: What does the log say here: `NSLog(@"types====%@",type);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Change every part you use `==` to compare string to `isEqualToString:`

For example:
Change

```
if (type == CellIdentifier)
```

To

```
if([type isEqualToString:CellIdentifier])
```

Comment: thanks but the output is same, I want to display each cell based on the type coming from server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Switch Condition rather If and else if

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you consider rethinking the whole logic.

I would do the same thing like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *type = [[myaray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"type"];
    myCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellid" ];
    if(myCell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *arr= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if(types isEqualToString:@"reviews")
        {
           myCell=[arr objectAtIndex:0];    
        }
        else if(types isEqualToString:@"recipes")
        {
           myCell=[arr objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else if(types isEqualToString:@"easy_tips")
        {
           myCell=[arr objectAtIndex:2];
        }

   }


return myCell;

}
```

Create a UITableViewCell class 'CustomCell'.
Create three UITableViewCells in 'CustomCell.xib'. Each cell for each type, the whole xib will be having the identifier '*CustomCellid*'
Then the above code would give you desired result. give a try